# What's the meaning of the idiom "on such accounts"?

Tags: idioms

Example usage in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning_(psychology)

> A similar understanding developed in **Cultural Studies of Science**: "Cultural studies thereby articulate dynamic, expressive conceptions of meaning, knowledge, and power, which contrast sharply with the standard approaches to these phenomena within philosophy and social theory (Rouse 1996,[5] 1999[6]). **On such accounts**, meaning is not a property of utterances or actions; the term `meaning' instead articulates the ways in which such performances inferentially draw upon and transform the field of prior performances in which they are situated." (Rouse, 2001, p. 3126)

Comment: The phrase "such accounts" refers to accounts (of phenomena) that are based on the "cultural studies of science" analytical model. The phrase "on such accounts" is not an idiom, and I think that the sentence you cite would be improved by changing "On such accounts" to "According to such accounts" or "In such accounts." I suspect that the author may have been led astray by the felt influence of a very different idiomatic phrase: "on account of" which means "because of." In any case, the original wording "on such accounts" is very poor in this particular instance

Comment: *By such accounts*? *in such accounts*?  It's impossible to tell from the context because that context (the quote from Rouse) has no discernible meaning in English.

Comment: Not an idiom. Just 3 words, with their usual meanings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an *idiom*. About reopening questions, see: [Notes to Reviewers (trial)](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7839/142322)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it is an idiom; however, "on such accounts" is a slightly more complex wording of "in those cases/instances."